# Variance term in ARIMA time series errors model

Tags: matlab, arima

I'm working with the [regARIMA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/regarima-class.html?searchHighlight=regarima) class in Matlab which generates an ARIMA time series error model. One of the parameters which is necessary when you specify the model is the "Variance" which is defined as "variance of the model innovations $\varepsilon_t$". Is there a simple explanation as to what this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance is the control to introduce randomness around a nominal/predicted value. The larger the variance the less obvious will be the signal that you are injecting/creating. The smaller the variance the more the simulated data becomes deterministic i.e. approaching an R-squared of 1. when you analyze the simulated series. Try specifying .1 then 1 then 10 and compare the three resultant series. It would be convenient if you could specify the "seed" for the random input to make your comparison.